# Emacs auto-indent tabs instead of spaces

Tags: emacs, tabs, space, auto-indent

I'm about to set EMACS put tabs instead of spaces when auto-indent, but cannot find any clue in the manual.

I tried this:
`(setq standard-indent 8)
(setq-default tab-width 8)`, but somewhy there is still 2 characters instead of 8, and they are **spaces**, not **tabs**.

Answer (score 0):

Major modes can override indentation settings.  Whatever major mode you are using apparently overrides the indentation offset as well as `indent-tabs-mode`.

To re-enable tabs again, define the following function, and add it the hook of the affected major mode:

```
(defun my-enable-tabs ()
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t))
```

Take care, though, because a major mode normally has a good reason to apply specific indentation setting.

Comment: You can also add such a function to the mode hook for the mode in question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your init file (`~/.emacs`), to turn off `indent-tabs-mode` by default, everywhere.

Yes, as @lunaryorn notes, other code (e.g. a mode) can override this default setting. But it is still your friend, so you start out right, everywhere.